# check real-ip IP address with javascript for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code as part of a nodejs application that runs behind an nginx proxy:

```
var ip_address = (request.headers['x-real-ip']);
if (ip_address !== "127.0.0.1") {
    var ip = request.headers['x-real-ip'];
    console.log(ip);    
}
else {
    var ip = "173.194.41.100";
    console.log(ip);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is that on my local dev machine, for testing i use a fixed IP address, otherwise it reads the x-real-ip from the request header.

My question, is there a way to make this more full proof, for example, is there a way to by pass this loop thus making the var ip return null, which would create a traceback on my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question, is there a way to make this more full proof, for example, is there a way to by pass this loop thus making the var ip return null, which would create a traceback on my app?

If you change it slightly, we can be sure that `ip` will not be `null`:

```
var ip, ip_address;
ip = ip_address = request.headers['x-real-ip'];
if (ip === null || ip === "127.0.0.1") {
    ip = "173.194.41.100";
}
console.log(ip);
```

Your original code would make `ip` `null` if `request.headers['x-real-ip']` evaluated to `null`, because your condition (`ip_address !== "127.0.0.1"`) would be `true`, and you'd grab `request.headers['x-real-ip']` (`null`) into `ip`.

With the modified code above, we don't have that problem, and we've been able to make it a bit more concise as well.

Comment: @ kninester: Good deal, glad that helped. BTW, I just edited it slightly as I realized you were declaring both `ip` and `ip_address` in the code that you posted, and I was only declaring `ip` (assuming `ip_address` to be already declared, which it wasn't).

Comment: thanks, in fact i didn't really needed to have it both declared, here is the code https://github.com/nkhine/phoenix/blob/master/ui/core/js/node/lib/zmgc.js#L72

Comment: @ khinester: Ah, good -- I thought maybe you were keeping the raw value around for some other reason. :-)